# UTF8 mb_strpos ISSUE

Tags: php, utf-8, strpos

I am facing realy strange problem i am trying to find a UTF-8 needle in UTF-8 haystack and it just dont want to work properly. Here is an example.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

vardump(mb_strpos('Příkon', 'Příkon '));
```

It returns false

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

vardump(mb_strpos('Příkon', 'Příkon'));
```

this returns 0 (success)

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry issue solved... i swaped a needle and haystack

Comment: if it returns 0 it means the string was found at the first char which is ok

Comment: vardump must be var_dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes. The error is correct. You've just swapped the `$haystack` and `$needle` when calling [`mb_strpos(string $haystack , string $needle)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) and so `'Příkon '` can not be found in `'Příkon'`. Your call should look like

```
mb_strpos('Příkon ', 'Příkon');
```